# array error expects .class

Tags: java, arrays, compiler-errors

I cannot figure why this isn't work it's expecting a . class error?
Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks!

```
public static int displayPercentageAndGrade(int assignMax, int assignScoreArray, int labMax, int labScoreArray, int quizMax,int quizScoreArray,int examScoreArray,int finalExam)


{ if (numArray.length%2)
        double median = ((double)assignScoreArray[assignScoreArray.length/2] + (double)assignScoreArray[assignScoreArray.length/2+1])/2;
        else
        double median = (double) numArray[numArray.length/2];
      double assignmentsPercent = (median / (numAssignments*assignMax)*100);
```

Error that comes up...
CSCD210Lab8Functions.java:109: '.class' expected
        double median = ((double)assignScoreArray[assignScoreArray.length/2] + (double)assignScoreArray[assignScoreArray.length/2+1])/2;

thanks for any help guys really stuck on this

Comment: `assignScoreArray` is of type `int`. It is not an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter in your method is  **int assignScoreArray**, it is just a type of int.

It seems you want to get the double value from array.

Have a try to change **int assignScoreArray** to **double[] assignScoreArray**

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your method definition:

```
public static int displayPercentageAndGrade(int assignMax, int assignScoreArray, 
            int labMax, int labScoreArray, int quizMax,int quizScoreArray,
            int examScoreArray,int finalExam)
```

to:

```
public static int displayPercentageAndGrade(int assignMax, int[] assignScoreArray, 
            int labMax, int[] labScoreArray, int quizMax,int[] quizScoreArray,
            int[] examScoreArray,int finalExam)
```

Assuming `assignScoreArray` is an int array. You may want to review the type of the parameters.